# Why can't I access to jLib.method() directly?

Tags: javascript, prototype, instance, anonymous-function

This is my first question...

I'm going to develop my own javascript library with a jQuery-like syntax.
I wrote this code:

```
(function(window)
{
    // Returns new instance
    var jLib = function( args ) { return new MyLib(args); };

    var MyLib = function( args )
    {
        // [...]
        /* This runs perfectly */

        return this;
    };

    /* I can't understand why jLib.byId() is undefined! */
    MyLib.lib = MyLib.prototype = {
        byId: function( id ) { return MyLib("#" + id); },

        /** Other code **/
    };

  // Add it to the window object
  if(!window.jLib) window.jLib = jLib;
})(window);
```

But if I try to run jLib.byId() it throws "undefined is not a funcion".

Could you explain me why?

Comment: `jLib` is a function.  It doesn't have a `byId` property.  You want `jLib().byId()`.  You need to *call* `jLib` and get the `new MyLib` object it returns.  P.S. You don't need `return this;` in the `MyLib` function`.

Comment: So I have to set a byId() function for jLib...

Can't I just set the same prototype for both?

Comment: If you want to be able to do `jLib.byId()`, then you will need to set a `byId` property on the `jLib` function.  Setting `jLib`'s `prototype` will only help you if you do `new jLib()`.  How *exactly* do you want to call `byId()`?  Why do you have both `MyLib` and `jLib`?

Comment: I am following this guide (where Library is MyLib): http://www.codephun.com/how-to-create-a-simple-javascript-library-like-jquery/

I want to be able to call jLib.byId(id)

Comment: Then you would have to set `jLib.byId` to something so you can use it.  For example, `jLib.byId = function(){};`.

Comment: So I could do something like jLib.byId = function( id ) { return MyLib.byId(id); };... Given that I wonder why jQuery uses the same name for lib in its source... well, thanks a lot Rocket

Comment: It would actually need to be `jLib.byId = function( id ) { return MyLib.lib.byId(id); };`.  What do you mean by "jQuery uses the same name for lib in its source"?  What's your wonder?

Comment: Also, when you are setting `MyLib.prototype` (or `MyLib.lib`), you are setting the properties that exist on *instances* of `MyLib`.  `jLib`, in this case is just a function that returns you a new `MyLib` instance.

Comment: MyLib.lib is linked to the prototype

Comment: Yes, just like `jQuery.fn`.  That's just done for syntactic sugar.

Comment: So MyLib.lib is not the prototype?

Comment: `MyLib.lib` *is* the prototype, yes.

Comment: So why to call MyLib.lib.method() and not directly MyLib.method()? I don't want to write all the functions for both jLib and MyLib twice... Am I wrong?

Comment: `MyLib.method` doesn't exist.  Methods on the `prototype` only exist on *instances* of `MyLib`.  Like if you did `var x = new MyLib('abc');`, then you could do `x.method()`.  `MyLib.lib` is just a reference to the prototype object.

Comment: Understood. To make jLib.method() work without writing twice the code, how should I call then?

Comment: You can loop over `MyLib.lib` and copy the properties you want onto `jLib`.  `for(var method in MyLib.lib){ jLib[method] = MyLib.lib[method]; }`.

Comment: Thanks, so I just place this before the window object is checked at the end of the anonymous function

Comment: Yeah, that could work.  All it's doing is copying the methods :)

Comment: For some reason I can't vote you up from Android app of the website, btw thanks a lot, yersh! :D